# How to create a database of information that shows as a list in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, content-database, database

So I have been given the task of creating a database of phone numbers, it will just need a few fields; number, room, building maybe a few more. It needs to be searchable and it needs to have the ability for users to submit updated information but it must go through an approver group. It also needs to be populate-able in a list.

Problem is I'm struggling with a start point, I know it has to be an SQL database.

Vague question I know but hopefully someone can glean something from what I am asking and say you will need X,Y and Z and then I can Google from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the header Question you can use `BCS` from more details check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163782.aspx)

Based on the mentioned requirements I think you don't need to build SQL database rather than using the list ! I suggest to Continue working with List.

I advise thinking to SQL Database only for complicated ERD and big data.

Regarding How you apply that it depend on your experience and your think, so I can tell you the features that will help you in SharePoint for this scenario

- Manage Permission at the list and creating  custom permission level for the only edit.
- Regarding search, you should use the search button at the top list of use built-in sort and filter, I also will support you with auto search filter via javascript. but let me open my VM.
- regarding approve , you have to build workflow on a list based on your approval cycle or use the default approval workflow.

Hope that helps you

Comment: I am also here if you need any clarification :)

Comment: Cheers for the reply. The list will likely include a few thousand phone numbers, this is why I think an SQL table would be required.

Comment: no problem you have to store  30,000,000 items per list (5000 threshold) see that https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/05/compare-sharepoint-2016-list-library-limits-with-sharepoint-2013-2010/

Comment: I've been googling and would using BCS help? would that allow 2 way syncing, i.e. would it let my users update the info and another approve the change.

Comment: yes allow read and write 2 way syncing but note that  BCS work with External list that not support SharePoint workflow read more about BCS limitation https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/01/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/